# Need to Read a Line Ahead Without Reading Two Lines at a Time (Python)

Tags: python, loops, iteration, readline

I'm working on a python code that reads a text file line-by-line and prints the line and the next line if the line starts with ">" and the next line starts with "G". To illustrate, I want the following input file...

```
>mm10_sample_name_here
GATCGATGCTGCTAGTAGCATG
>mm10_sample_name_here
>mm10_sample_name_here
AATCGATGCTGCTAGTAGCATG
>mm10_sample_name_here
>mm10_sample_name_here
>mm10_sample_name_here
GATCGATGCTGCTAGTAGCATG
```

To output as...

```
>mm10_sample_name_here
GATCGATGCTGCTAGTAGCATG
>mm10_sample_name_here
GATCGATGCTGCTAGTAGCATG
>mm10_sample_name_here
GATCGATGCTGCTAGTAGCATG
```

I've tried using next() in the following...

```
original_file = 'test_input_file.txt'
file_destination = 'test_output_file.txt'

import os
if os.path.exists(file_destination):
  os.remove(file_destination)

f=open(original_file, 'r+')

for line in f:
  try:
    line2 = next(f)
  except StopIteration:
    line2 = ""
  if line2.startswith("G") and line.startswith(">"):
    with open(file_destination, "a") as myfile:
       myfile.write(line)
       myfile.write(line2)
```

However, it reads the input file two lines at a time meaning that once a line fails the if condition, all further lines are mismatched. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out, your solution doesn't work. You are advancing the generator by two items on every iteration (since you call next()). You need to use a strategy to only advance the generator once. One would be to keep state while looping, e.g.

```
previous_line = ""
for line in f:
  if line.startswith("G") and previous_line.startswith(">"):
    ...
  previous_line = line
```

You could also keep the next() function and use e.g. `while True:`, but beware of the edge case when there are multiple lines starting with ">".

Comment: Your strategy to move the generator one line at a time and check the previous line worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess as to what you want to do.  You leave out the edge conditions, like what if you get a `G` on the first line, so it is necessarily incomplete.

This is a simple procedural approach, which triggers on the 'G' and only prints if the previous line was a `>`.  Its easier that way rather than looking forward.

```
for line in open(file):
    if line.startswith('>'):
        last_line = line

    elif line.startswith('G') and last_line:
        print(last_line)
        print(line)
        last_line = None
```